# How to visualize recorded audio from Blob with AudioContext?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have successfully created an audio wave visualizer based on the [mdn example here](https://github.com/mdn/voice-change-o-matic). I now want to add visualization for recorded audio as well. I record the audio using MediaRecorder and save the result as a Blob. However I cannot find a way to connect my AudioContext to the Blob.

This is the relevant code part so far:

```
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        
if (mediaStream instanceof Blob)
    // Recorded audio - does not work
    var stream = URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream);
else
    // Stream from the microphone - works
    stream = mediaStream;

var source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
source.connect(analyser);
```

mediaStream comes from either:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({
    audio: this.audioConstraints,
    video: this.videoConstraints,
})
.then( stream => {
      mediaStream = stream;
}
```

or as a result of the recorded data:

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
    mediaChunks.push(event.data);
});
...
mediaStream = new Blob(mediaChunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm' });
```

How do I connect the AudioContext to the recorded audio? Is it possible with a Blob? Do I need something else? What am I missing?

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirschkern/atwu1zhj/5/). The relevant part starts at line 118.

Thanks for help and suggestions.

EDIT:
Thanks to Johannes Klauß, I've found a solution.
See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kirschkern/xm9b5g4L/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Response API to create an ArrayBuffer and decode that with the audio context to create an AudioBuffer which you can connect to the analyser:

```js
mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
    mediaChunks.push(event.data);
});
...
const arrayBuffer = await new Response(new Blob(mediaChunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm' })).arrayBuffer();
const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);

const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
source.connect(analyser);
```

Comment: thanks for pushing in the right direction. I've tried it but the audioBuffer doesn't have a connect method.
I've now tried                 const arrayBuffer = await new Response(this.stream).arrayBuffer();
                const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
                source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
                source.buffer = audioBuffer;
                source.connect(analyser);
But I don't get any visualization.

Comment: That is the correct way to go (sorry, that I missed the AudioBufferSourceNode). Did you check if the audio buffer has any content? Or did you connect the BufferSourceNode to the audio context destination to check if it plays back?

Comment: Thanks Johannes for comming back. Not sure what I'm missing. I've created a testcase here: https://jsfiddle.net/kirschkern/atwu1zhj/5/
The relevant part starts at line 118.

Comment: Well on Line 44 is the only time you call `visualize`. You never call it again, so the audioBufferSource will never connect to the analyser node.

Comment: This makes sense. And starting the audio :-) 
Now it works. See the updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/kirschkern/xm9b5g4L/1/
Thanks a lot for your great support!